# Can I claim the child care tax credit in addition to using a dependent care FSA?

Tags: united-states, tax-credit, fsa, child-care

Dependent care FSA is capped at $5000 annually and I use this entirely.

The annual child care credit is $3000.

If my expenses are over $8000, can I utilize both of these in the same calendar year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's either/or. For those who are able to take the credit, the math usually favors that option.

Comment: In my situation my effective tax bracket is ~30% and our household combined income is ~$140,000. We have one child. Unless I've done some math wrong the cost favors the FSA.